# Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/josh/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist` exited with 5

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

When trying to start postgresql

```
➜  ~ brew services start postgresql
Warning: Use postgresql@14 instead of deprecated postgresql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/josh/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist` exited with 5.
```

Getting "error" as status when running brew services list

```
➜  ~ brew services list
Name          Status     User File
postgresql@14 error  256 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
```

PSQL was working perfectly fine, shut down my laptop (did not update) and when I turned it on the next day psql was not working. I am on OSX Version 12.6 (Monteray).

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue on 13.0 on M1 pro, all is did was `brew services restart postgresql@14`, it shut down, restarted and ran fine, issue gone.

Comment: Thank you. I encountered the same issue with mysql service and this solution also worked for it.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same error today  on my Mac Ventura 13.0. Did these steps and it helped.

1. Run `rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@{YOUR_VERSION}/postmaster.pid` to remove `postmaster.pid` file. this is usually caused by an error in the `postmaster.pid` file.
2. Run `brew services stop postgresql` to stop the current postgresql service.
3. Then finally run `brew services start postgresql`, a new `postmaster.pid` file will be generated.

If this doesn't work you can run `brew doctor` and see if it will return `Your system is ready to brew`. If there are warnings , you can share them here with the community for more details.?

Comment: For me it was `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` (no version suffix even though i use `brew services start postgresql@14` to run it)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, but couldn't get Postgres 14 working, and ended up just upgrading to Postgres 15, which I did get to work.

The steps looked like this (version numbers might vary)

```bash
brew services stop postgresql@14
brew install postgresql@15
# This command will copy data over to the new database
brew /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.1/bin/pg_upgrade -b /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/bin/ -d /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/ -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/
brew services start postgresql@15
```

Comment: Just FYI, the command brew /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.1/bin/pg_upgrade -b /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/bin/ -d /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/ -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/ didn't work

Answer (score 1):

For Apple Silicon M1/M2 Mac OS Ventura 13.x.x ,following steps worked for me:

1. `cd /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/`
2. Check if `postmaster.pid` file exists by `ls postmaster.pid`
3. If it exists, run `rm postmaster.pid`
4. Finally,run `brew services restart postgresql`.
5. Check the status `brew services list`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had postgresql@13 and postgresql@14 install with brew on Ventura 13.1

I first removed postgresql@13 **and all data** within :

`brew remove postgresql@13` and `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgresql@13`

This assure me that the previous folder is fully remove, however, **I did not care about my local data ...** you may want to take care of it before doing this

After that, I reinstall postgresql@14 within the following commands :

```bash
# Remove postgresql 14 with brew 
brew remove postgresql@14

# Reinstall postgresql 14 with brew
brew install postgresql@14

# Remove all the files in the db folder
rf -rf /usr/local/var/postgresql@14/*

# Kill all process that run any db of the postgresql 14 folder 
pkill -f /usr/local/var/postgresql@14   
   
# Initialize the db folder for postgresql 14 
initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgresql@14

# Restart postgresql with brew (should say that it's already running) 
brew services start postgresql@14
```