# Impossible to run postgresql with homebrew

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install and run postgresql@14 on my Ventura 13.2.1 macbook.
But, the service is always at error 256 or 512 status.
I have tried every single solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364934/error-failure-while-executing-bin-launchctl-bootstrap-gui-501-users-josh-li), but without any success.
Here more details about it:

➜  ~ brew services list

Name              Status     User   File

mongodb-community started    adrien ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
postgresql@14     error  512 root   ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
unbound           none

➜  ~ tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log

postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.

➜  ~ initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data/

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "adrien".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "fr_FR.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "french".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /var/lib/postgres/data ... initdb: error: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgres": Permission denied

Comment: "Permission denied" is a problem about basic operating system management, bot about software development.

Comment: 1) Where did you install from here [Homebrew default](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql@14#default) or [Homebrew petere](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql)? 2) Did you follow the instructions here [Homebrew Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew)?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue.
What worked for me was to `brew uninstall postgresql`
and then `brew install postgresql@14`